# How Windows regional settings affect javafx application

Tags: java, javafx, regional-settings

I'm working on javafx application and i have noticed, that some CSSstyle/double functions not working properly, when Windows regional settings have been changed (i am from Estonia). 
When i open program window, some field are disabled (comboboxes and datepickers):
[image]
Disable code:

```
public void lockElements() {
    policyTypeCombo.setDisable(true);
    insurerCombo.setDisable(true);
    clientCombo.setDisable(true);
    startDate.setDisable(true);
}
```

After I click Unlock button this code works:

```
@FXML
public void unlockElements() {
    policyTypeCombo.setDisable(false);
    insurerCombo.setDisable(false);
    startDate.setDisable(false);
}
```

It is all very simple, and in my IntellijIdea everything works fine:
[image]
Also when i enter some Double in Sum text field, it should fill part1-12 sums automatically:
[image]
Here is code, that allows enter only double:

```
sumText.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
            if (!newValue.matches("\\d{0,7}([\\.]\\d{0,4})?")) {
                sumText.setText(oldValue);
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is part of the code, that fills other sums

```
double sum = Double.valueOf(sumText.getText());
                    double part = sum / 12d;
                    part1Sum.setText(String.format("%.2f", part));
                    part2Sum.setText(String.format("%.2f", part));
                    part3Sum.setText(String.format("%.2f", part));
                    part4Sum.setText(String.format("%.2f", part));
                    part5Sum.setText(String.format("%.2f", part));
                    part6Sum.setText(String.format("%.2f", part));
                    part7Sum.setText(String.format("%.2f", part));
                    part8Sum.setText(String.format("%.2f", part));
                    part9Sum.setText(String.format("%.2f", part));
                    part10Sum.setText(String.format("%.2f", part));
                    part11Sum.setText(String.format("%.2f", part));
                    part12Sum.setText(String.format("%.2f", part));
```

After packing my app and installing on my computer, everything works fine.
BUT on computers with different regional settings i have this picture: after clicking Unlock button, comboboxes and datepickers are still "light-gray"(but working, i can choose other options):
[image]
And when I enter new sum, 1-12 parts sums don't fill automatically.
As i understand, it is related somehow to Reginal decimal symbols or something like this. 
Question : how i can make my App independent from machine regional setting?

Comment: What version of JavaFX are you using? There was a bug affecting JavaFX 10 related to invalid rendering of disabled nodes—[JDK-8204949](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8204949). Though I don't think it was related to regional settings (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50800612/)).

Comment: @Slaw thank you, that helps in part of rendering, but in part of Double calculations problem still exists

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to rework the code into a [mcve] demonstrating the issue (i.e. a small example application)? Also, which locales are working and which aren't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone, thank you @Slaw. I solve this problem by using BigDecimal.
Code was:

```
double sum = Double.valueOf(sumText.getText());
                double part = sum / 12d;
                part1Sum.setText(String.format("%.2f", part));
                part2Sum.setText(String.format("%.2f", part));
                part3Sum.setText(String.format("%.2f", part));
                part4Sum.setText(String.format("%.2f", part));
                part5Sum.setText(String.format("%.2f", part));
                part6Sum.setText(String.format("%.2f", part));
                part7Sum.setText(String.format("%.2f", part));
                part8Sum.setText(String.format("%.2f", part));
                part9Sum.setText(String.format("%.2f", part));
                part10Sum.setText(String.format("%.2f", part));
                part11Sum.setText(String.format("%.2f", part));
                part12Sum.setText(String.format("%.2f", part));
```

I changed it to:

```
int scale = 2;
double sum = BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.valueOf(sumText.getText()) / 12d).setScale(scale, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).doubleValue();
                    part1Sum.setText(Double.toString(sum));
                    part2Sum.setText(Double.toString(sum));
                    part3Sum.setText(Double.toString(sum));
                    part4Sum.setText(Double.toString(sum));
                    part5Sum.setText(Double.toString(sum));
                    part6Sum.setText(Double.toString(sum));
                    part7Sum.setText(Double.toString(sum));
                    part8Sum.setText(Double.toString(sum));
                    part9Sum.setText(Double.toString(sum));
                    part10Sum.setText(Double.toString(sum));
                    part11Sum.setText(Double.toString(sum));
                    part12Sum.setText(Double.toString(sum));
```

Now everything is OK.